# Proving convergence of integrals

Tags: real-analysis

Q) Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$, where $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. Show that:

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)(1+e^{inx})|^2dx\to 2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2dx, \text{ as }n\to \infty$$

**EDIT:**

Answer: As stated in the hint,

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)(1+e^{inx})|^2dx &= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2|(1+e^{inx})|^2dx\\
&= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2(2+2\cos nx)dx \\
&= 2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2 + 2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2 \cos nx \\
&\to 2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2 \text{ the second term converges to 0 by Riemann Lebesgue lemma}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: just expand $|1+e^{inx}|^{2}$  as $2+2\cos (nx)$ and use Riemann Lebesgue Lemma for $\int |f(x)|^{2} \cos (nx) dx$.